# Why is the nth prime less than or equal to the factorial of the previous prime plus 1?

Tags: number-theory, logic

In Godel's 1931 proof he presents a series of primitive recursive
functions. One of them is Pr (n) which returns the n'th prime
(in order of magnitude). Pr (0) is defined to be 0.
Pr (n + 1) returns the smallest y such that y <= {Pr (n)}! + 1 (plus some
other conditions on y such as y needs to be prime and y needs to be
greater than Pr (n) [ the previous prime ].
Where ! is the factorial function.

I am not a mathematician but how do you know that the n'th prime
is less than or equal to the factorial of the previous
prime (plus 1)?

Comment: Consider a prime $p$. Then $p! + 1$ has some prime factor $q$, and we cannot have $q \leq p$. So there is a prime $q$ such that $p < q \leq p! + 1$. In particular, let $r$ be the smallest prime bigger than $p$; then $p < r \leq q \leq p! + 1$.

Comment: See also: [Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem).

Comment: If you believe the question should be answered, please do so by posting an **answer**, *not* a **comment**. @MarkSaving

Comment: Think about what the prime decomposition of $n!$ looks like. What does that tell you about $n!+1$?

Comment: n! + 1 is not divisible by the previous primes.  I see that now thanks.

Comment: @Nij: I see nothing wrong with posting a solution as a comment. What are your reasons for objecting to this practice?

Comment: They can't be downvoted, they can't be edited, the formatting options are limited, and comments attempting to clarify them must be placed within the thread on the question instead of just that answer. Besides which, that's literally the system here. Do we need anything more than just "do it properly" to justify saying to do it properly?